# Node.Js - Jade form doesn't POST or do anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

**app.js**

```
   /**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);
app.get('/contact', routes.contact);

app.get('/moviesList', routes.moviesList);

app.get('/addMovie', routes.addMovie);

app.post('/movieAdded', routes.movieAdded);
```

**index.js**

```
exports.movieAdded = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.render('movieAdded', req.body);
};
```

**addMovie.jade**

```
extends layout

block content

    br
    form(action="/movieAdded", method="POST")
    input(type="text", name="movie" ,value="movie")
    br
    input(type="number", name="rating", value="rating")
    br
    input(type="number", name="year", value="year")
    br
    input(type="submit" value="Submit")
```

*When I hit submit button, it doesn't POST anything on the console or it doesn't show anything in the browser. In other words it is being idle. Tried many ways so any help would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tab in all the inputs:

```
extends layout

block content

br
form(action="/movieAdded", method="POST")
    input(type="text", name="movie" ,value="movie")
    br
    input(type="number", name="rating", value="rating")
    br
    input(type="number", name="year", value="year")
    br
    input(type="submit" value="Submit")
```

If you don't put a tab under form then it will render the inputs outside of form.

So, a tab is required to make all the inputs children of form.

Comment: When I use above code, the form itself doesn't show up. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

*I got it work*

```
  extends layout

    block content
        br
        form(action="movieAdded", method="post")
         | Movie:
         input(type="text", name="movie")
         br
         | Rating:
         input(type="number", name="rating")
         br
         input(type="submit", value="Submit")
```